# django modelform booleanfield not appearing as required

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to render a modelform which has a booleanfield from the model (with yes, no choices) that fails to appear as default (what I thought was the default).

the model field is:

```
BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))
same_address = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
```

And used in the form via (and not altered in the form constructor or elsewhere):

```
  ....
  class Meta:
    model = Address
    fields = [

        'same_address',
    ]
```

Comment: what version of Django are you using?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.11

Comment: I also have Django 1.11 and I cannot set choices directly on BooleanField inside model. Are you sure that you have run migrations without errors?